# React Native - Display:'None' on nested Text element

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
<View >
    <Text style={HomeStyles.homeSegmentText}>
        {currentUser.badgeId}   
        <Text style={!(this.props.expiryAlert) && {display:'none'}} )>
            <BlinkMe days={getDays()} />
        </Text>
    </Text>
</View>
```

In the above example I want the BlinkMe component to only ever display if expiryAlert is true - but the display:none is ignored in the nested text component regardless - does anyone have any ideas for a workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Display property isn't supported for the `Text` component, you should have a look at it [style's props](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text#style).

As a workaround you can do the following:

```
<View>
  <Text style={HomeStyles.homeSegmentText}>
    {currentUser.badgeId}
    {!(this.props.expiryAlert) &&
      <Text>
        <BlinkMe days={getDays()} />
      </Text>
    }
  </Text>
</View>
```